# SQL Linked Server Actively Refused

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, linked-server

I have access to our clients SQL server and have an IP Address, Port, Username & Password which allow connection via SSMS.

I am trying to setup a linked server to migrate their data into a test system am getting errors. We are running Server 2012, client 2008R2

Code I'm using to setup & test linked server:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
    @server = N'lnkServer'
,   @datasrc = N'IPADDRESS,PORT'
,   @srvproduct = N'SQLNCLI'
,   @provider = N'SQLNCLI'
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
    @rmtsrvname = N'lnkServer'
,   @useself = false
,   @rmtuser = N'userName'
,   @rmtpassword = N'passWord';
EXEC sp_testlinkedserver
    @servername = N'lnkServer'
```

Error I'm receiving:

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "lnkServer" returned message "Login timeout expired".
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "lnkServer" returned message "A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.".
Msg 10061, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

We have access to the server, and I can read all the tables, etc. through SSMS but cannot link. I do not have RDP access to the server that this is hosted on so any solution will need to be implemented from SSMS not the server setup.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: what does test connection say,when you click through ssms

Comment: "A network-related ... " check the server address and firewall

Comment: Exact text is too long to post as a comment but mirrors the error above.

Comment: Server address and firewall are all fine. I can connect directly through SSMS which validates this, just cannot create linked server.

Comment: Also around the firewall - I'm getting as part of the error "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it." That to me says that the request is getting there, but not being rejected for some reason.

Comment: @MatthewBaker the TCP connection is rejected by the machine itself. Which almost certainly means a firewall rule or wrong port. Does the firewall rule allow connection from anyone or specific IPs? Specific ports?

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis.  There is something odd rule wise here.  My local machine can connect via SSMS.  I installed SQL express on my machine, and that can link to our client.  But our main server cannot.  Got to be a rule somewhere, but have found the work around now. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help all.  Have found an odditiy around the outgoing connection from our server.  Have worked around this by Installing a local version of SQL on my box just to hose the linked servers.

Credit to [Panagiotis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos) for pushing me in the right direction even after I'd convinced myself he was wrong.